# Jersey testing PUT generates 404 local only

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a problem regarding my build process. We have a maven project and some JUnit tests for testing the REST server.

When i run `mvn build` locally, I always get an error at one test which puts a XML file and expects a 204 as result. Apparently, I always get a 404 although the URL is correct and the test **successfully** runs on Travis CI. Funny thing: it used to work at my local machine also and all other `assertPut()`s are working correctly.

This is the function I'm testing:

```
@Path("properties/")
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response putProperties(@RestDocParam(description = "") Document doc) {
    // store element
}
```

The accoring test:

```
@Test
public void addProperties() throws Exception {
    this.assertPut("properties/","properties.xml");
}

public void assertPut(String restURL, String fileName) {
    String contents = readFromClasspath(fileName);
    start()
            .body(contents)
            .contentType(getAccept(fileName))
            .put(callURL(restURL))
            .then()
            .statusCode(204);
}
```

I also tested it with different Java versions but always on a Windows 10 machine with maven version 3.5.0. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: If you running on travis can you give a link to the project to see how the pom file looks like etc. ?

Comment: Sorry but it's a private repository, but as I said, it used to work and nothing was changed in the config files.